# Вертикальное выравнивание текста в блоке неизвестной высоты

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли способ выровнять текст в блоке с неизвестной заранее высотой по центру, используя блочную верстку?

<div>
    <span>Текст, кот. должен быть выровнен по центру</span>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуглите *display:table;* и *display:table-cell;* — выравнивание будет так же работать, как в таблице. [Вот песочница](http://jsfiddle.net/2ChzJ/). Но нельзя просто так брать и использовать *display:table-cell* — сначала нужно обернуть в блок с *display:table*.

Comment: Просят же с неизвестной высотой, a вы даете пример с фиксированной высотой.

Comment: @RomanLipatov добро пожаловать на SO на русском. Публикация ответов - только для решений. Для уточнений, предложений и конструктивной критики есть комментарии, они вам будут доступны после 50 репутации.